# Add the title of a widget as an ID - for anchor links

Tags: functions, theme-development, widgets, sidebar, register-sidebar

I'm currently building a WordPress theme where my page consists of widgets. One widget is a part of the page. I'd like to be able to use anchor links with them, and to do this, I would like to output the widget's title as an ID of the widget.

I know the widget has and ID already but it results in ugly anchor links - the anchor link would be `url.com/#text-2`. I would like it to be `url.com/#about`.

In the source code, this is the default HTML output:

`<div id="text-2" class="widget-container widget_text">`

This is the HTML output I aim for:

`<div id="text-2 about" class="widget-container widget_text">`

How do I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

---

Update:

It seems an HTML element can't have two ID's.

Is it possible to instead add an `<a>` element within the widget's `widget-title` where the ID of the `<a>` is the widget's title?

So the HTML output looks like this:
`<h2 class="widget-title"><a id="about">About</a></h2>`

Comment: a html element cannot have 2 id's - an ID is a unique identifier. You would have to create a new widget, give it the ID you want. I had to do this on a project I did recently, just recreated the widget I needed and changed the id and name to match my project

Comment: Okay, I see. Thank you for clarifying that. I could achieve the same thing by adding a `<a>` element to the `widget-title`, so I edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can add an  around the title of the widget, you do this in the register_sidebar code which you would put in your functions.php

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'theme_register_sidebars' );
function theme_register_sidebars() {
 register_sidebar(
  array(
   'id' => 'mysidebar-sidebar',
   'name' => __( 'My Sidebar', 'themename' ),
   'description' => __( 'Widgets for my sidebar', 'themename' ),
   'before_widget' => '<div class="widget">',
   'after_widget' => '</div>',
   'before_title' => '<h2 class="widget-title"><a id="about">',
   'after_title' => '</a></h2>'
  )
 );
}
```

You create the new "widget area" or sidebar which you then put in actual widget in.

jQuery Version (not tested):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 $( '#id h2.widget-title').wrapInner( "<a id="about"></a>" );
});
```

You would then add the jQuery either to a JS file and [Enqueue](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) it or put it into wp_footer using the filter of the same name ([link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_footer))

Comment: Thanks, but I would prefer to use the same sidebar for all my widgets.

Comment: You would then need to either, add the <a> using jQuery or php (using preg_replace).

I will add a jQuery solution to my post.

Comment: That sounds great!

Comment: The jQuery code works! The perfect solution would be not having to add that code for each widget but it sure is a lot more flexible than adding a sidebar for each widget. Thank you! :)

Comment: my pleasure, glad I could help :)

Answer (score -1):

I was searching for a simplier way and I turned around by just adding a   `<span id="youranchornametag">First words/text of the element</span>`
Now you call it from where ever you like `http://.../#youranchornametag`.